# Vue js and W3C HTML Validator

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, w3c-validation

I am currently working on a SPA using Vue, but I can't validate it through the W3C's HTML Validator. How can I validate it? I have heard of adding "data-" just before the Vue syntax, but it does not work. Here it is some of my code:

```
<div class="row" v-for="(c, index) in contactos" :key="index">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <p>{{ c.nombre }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <p>{{ c.email }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <p>{{ c.numTel }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" v-on:click="deleteContact(c.id, index)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also attach a link to some of the errors in the validation:
[HTML W3C validation errors example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOhOI.png)

Comment: Please, don't post with links to externar image source.   The post must content the whole information.

Comment: Try this one: http://validator.w3.org/nu/ though vue has its own ways to validate the dom *works*, linters help with bad coding and property order etc etc.. the Geocities style W3C badge, doesn't add much.

Answer (score -2):

Also you can validate your HTML code before adding vue-specific things